# Chrome Extension Inline install procedure

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**UPDATE:** Google has disabled inline installation feature for Chrome extensions.

```
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID">
```

I have added above code on my html page (my website hit by user) which is associated with my chrome extension already published in chrome store and javascript function `chrome.webstore.install()`.

Will it really make user to install the chrome extension in his computer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation

First off, for this to work, you will need to verify the website as something you own via Webmaster Tools.

> ### Verified site requirement
>
> For security reasons, inline installations can only be initiated by a page on a site that is [verified](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34592) (via [Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/)) as being associated with that item in the Chrome Web Store. Note that if you verify ownership for a domain (for example, http://example.com) you can initiate inline installation from any subdomain or page (for example, http://app.example.com or http://example.com/page.html).

Once you verified your site, you need to edit your extension listing via Developer Console to select that the extension is associated with your (verified) site:

[image: Developer Dashboard]

---

If you have done all that, added the link tag and triggered the `install()` function (which, if I remember correctly, has to be triggered by a user action, like a click handler), the user will be presented with a small dialog describing your extension, something like that:

[image: Example]

There, they can accept or deny without opening Web Store. You cannot silently install an extension, but you can save the user the trouble of going to the Store listing.

Comment: thank you so much . yes i have domain and sub domain one more thing as you can see <link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID">  itemID so this ID will be provided by chrome after publishing the extension right?

Comment: It should already be available when you submit the extension to the web store, even before publishing. Go to [Developer Dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) and click on "More Info" next to your extension.

Comment: is there any other alternative other than verifying my site? If that's the only way to do. How do I verify my site hosted locally?

Comment: @GokulanPH Not clear what your use case is. It's best if you ask a separate question with more details of your setup and requirements.