# Chrome store inline install - making it work

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have read all of the questions in that subject on this website and others, so (please) bear with me for this:

- Uploaded a website and extension.
- After the extension was approved - I put the Google tag + Google's provided
  file in my website's library so that it will be validated. Got a green light 
  on that from Google.
- Enabled the inline installation from the chrome-store's dev dashboard
- selected the http://... under the "Verify that this is an official item for a website you own:"

Now, moved on to the actual script for invoking the in-line install:

```
<head>
...   
<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/(my extension's id)">
...
</head>
<body>
...
<button onclick="test()"> test</button>
    <script>
        function test() {
            chrome.webstore.install("https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/(my extension's id)", function (a) {
                alert("Success! " + a);
            }, function (a) {
                alert("Fail! " + a);
            });
        }
    </script>
...
</body>
```

I keep getting the remark many had quoted (in the sample I print it to a dialog for my own convenience):

> Inline installs can only be initiated for Chrome Web Store items that
>   have one or more verified sites

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong, would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818685/chrome-extension-inline-install-procedure) if it can help you.

Comment: Theank @KENdi I did go through that and did everything as instructed. However, no luck so I turned to posting the above. My only suspicion is perhaps the facts that I did add to my 'approved' properties in [https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home]  two  versions of my url - one with 'www', the second without. the one without doesn't seem to be fully 'healthy', something to do with the robots.txt file (which I corrected but stil a warning sign appears). I still can't seem to get the inline to work...